# c# equivalent of nodejs code

Tags: c#, node.js

I need c# equivalent of the below nodejs code. I have some c# code, but the results are not the same.

//working node code below

```
    Ice3x.prototype._signMessage = function (message) {
  var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512',new Buffer(this.secret, 'base64'));
  hmac.update(message);
  var signature = hmac.digest('base64');
  return signature;
}
```

//c# code below

```
   public class HmacSignatureCalculator : ICalculteSignature
    {
        public string Signature(string secret, string value)
        {
            var secretBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
            var valueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
            string signature;

            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512(secretBytes))
            {
                var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(valueBytes);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }
            return signature;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the difference comes from the way the secret is encoded. In the node version it assumes that it represents a base64 encoded byte array, whereas in your C# version you treat it as a normal string.

So in your C# version read the byte array from the base 64 encoded secret:

```
var secretBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secret);
```

Now you are consistent with the node version:

```
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', new Buffer(this.secret, 'base64'));
```

Comment: Thanks .. just to add.